# php find average time in minutes seconds milliseconds

Tags: php, datetime, average

I currently have an array that is formatted like this `array($time,$time,$time,$time,$time, $time)` where `$time` is a string formatted like so `m:ss:MM` where `m`=minutes, `s`=seconds and `M`=milliseconds.

How would I do this?
I have a rough idea on how to do this which is:

convert each string into a timestamp
loop through array and calling an average function or do maths calculation (not sure how it works with unix timestamps).

Thanks for the help

Comment: I believe there is no magic function in PHP for that. You would have to write something to sum up all the values and then divide by the number of elements. You can create a function for that by inputting two values and exploding the time, summing the values, validating (like if seconds is bigger than 60, you can turn it into an extra hour) and then you can do the same for dividing by the number of elements so you can finally have the average time.

Comment: @MatheusLoureiro could you show me the code for that? Im a newbie to web development. Thanks. If it works I shall uproot and mark as answered.

Comment: I just added an answer as it didn't fit as a comment.

Comment: Take a look at [my Time value class](https://github.com/vascowhite/Time) it does what you wan't out of the tin and much more besides.

Comment: @vascowhite does this support my time format? Also does it display the output in the same format too? Doesn't look like it does.

Comment: @iProgram sorry, didn't notice you were using microseconds. I can probably extend it to use microseconds, keep checking for an update if you don't find another solution.

Comment: @vascowhite Thats ok. Also Im using milliseconds, not microseconds. 1ms = 1000us. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no magic function in PHP for that. You would have to write something to sum up all the values and then divide by the number of elements. You can create a function for that by inputting two values and exploding the time, summing the values, validating (like if seconds is bigger than 60, you can turn it into an extra minute) and then you can do the same for dividing by the number of elements so you can finally have the average time.

The sum function would be something like this:

```
function sumTime($time1, $time2) {

    $time1Exp = explode(':', $time1);
    $time2Exp = explode(':', $time2);
    $timeResult = array();
    $extraMinutes = $extraSeconds = 0;

    //sum milliseconds
    $timeResult[2] = $time1Exp[2] + $time2Exp[2];

    if($timeResult[2] >= 100) {
        $extraSeconds = floor($timeResult[2] / 100);
        $timeResult[2] -= $extraSeconds * 100;
    }

    $timeResult[1] = $time1Exp[1] + $time2Exp[1] + $extraSeconds;

    if($timeResult[1] >= 60) {
        $extraMinutes = floor($timeResult[1] / 60);
        $timeResult[1] -= $extraMinutes * 100;
    }

    $timeResult[0] = $time1Exp[0] + $time2Exp[0] + $extraMinutes;

    return implode(':', $timeResult);


}
```

Comment: How would I get it to do an unlimited amount of arguments? The function will be expecting a minimum of 14 times and maximum of 17.

Comment: You would have to do a `foreach` in your array to sum all the values and then divide by the number of values which you can get with `array_count()` function.

Comment: FWIW, you can simply start with a `$result = '00:00:00';` variable before the foreach loop and then in the loop you go with `$result = sumTime($result, $timeOfThisLoop);`. After the loop is over you'll have in the `$result` variable the final sum. Basically you also have to create a function based on the same algorithm that I wrote which you might want to call `divideTime()` and get the average doing like `$average = divideTime($result, $numberOfElements);`.

Comment: Sorry, Don't quite get it. Could you put the code in the answer so it is easier to understand?

Comment: @iProgram, this site was made to help people with their doubts, issues etc, but not to develop stuff for free. I have wrote the more complex part of the code you need. You have to get things from here and do your own code, and any doubt you have, you can ask here, but I won't code it for you. Perhaps you want either a teacher or a developer, which you'll have to pay to get it. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Sorry, Its that I am very new to this language. I understand what you are meaning though.